# how to run multiple Django project in using on Nginx and Gunicorn on docker(two diffrent django servers with diffent ports)

Tags: django, docker, nginx

```
need to docker nginx configuration
this is how basic nginx setup works for a single service
```

nginx
├── Dockerfile
└── nginx.conf
Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

nginx.conf:

upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Then, update the web service, in docker-compose.prod.yml, replacing ports with expose:

****Then, update the web service, in docker-compose****

```
 web:
      build:
        context: ./app
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
      expose:
        - 8000
      env_file:
        - ./.env.prod
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  Is the Nginx proxy in the same Compose file as the Django container(s)?  The question title suggests a second Django container; how is that started and referenced?

Comment: (Compose `expose:` does more or less nothing at all, and you can delete that block entirely.  You also shouldn't need to provide a `command:` override, normally a container will run the Dockerfile `CMD`.)